# How do you unit test a custom React function using enzyme, mocha, chai

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

My question is how I would test a custom function which changes a parameter. I want to test if a given uni such as 'University of cambridge passed as prob, will give me 'University...' as it should truncate after 10 characters. Basically I want to check if the changeName method is working

```
const University = ({ Name }) => (

 renderUni(uniUrl, uniName) {
  const truncateName = changenName(uniName);
  return <Chevron className="chevronuni" /> {truncateName} + '...';
}

 changeName(Name) {
  const maxCharacterLength = 10;
  if (Name.length > 10) {
    return Name.substring(0, maxCharacterLength);
  }
  return Name;
}
  <div className="uni">
    <ul className="uni-login">
          {Name &&
           Name.map(({ uniUrl, uniName }) =>
              (<li>
                {renderUni(uniUrl, uniName)}
              </li>)
          )}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: You've got a few syntax issues above, it might be worth reviewing them.

Comment: The changeName function can be a function on its own that can be tested separately without instantiating a component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to assert the output of your component with enzyme, one approach is to use [shallow render](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md), e.g.

```
const { shallow } = require('enzyme');

it('truncates the university name', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<University Name={[ { uniUrl: '', uniName: 'University of Cambridge' } ]} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('li').text()).to.be('University...');
});
```

If you're not particularly concerned about the finer details of your components output such as peripheral presentational mark-up / text you may find [`contains`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/contains.md) to be of use, e.g.

```
const { shallow } = require('enzyme');

it('truncates the university name', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<University Name={[ { uniUrl: '', uniName: 'University of Cambridge' } ]} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('li').contains('University...')).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: This answer is great, however if i had a chevron tag before the truncated name this would not work. How would i change so that the chevron doesnt appear in the test. See edited code above